# While deploying the app the string value is getting converted into lower case, how to keep the original data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, deployment

I have an image named as Grass.jpeg and I am setting the image path to src tag in my react app like this.

```
  <img src = "gallery/Grass.jpeg" />
```

I am running the app locally, its working.
Now I have hosted my app in AWS, the image name is getting converted to lowercase because of which the image is broken.

In hosted app, the image tag is like this:

```
<img src = "gallery/grass.jpeg"/>
```

What should I do

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using capitalized filenames is a bad choice generally in this scenario, in my opinion, but is your bundling or deployment process modifying the filename? Perhaps you're using some kind of lowercase transform option?

Comment: Yes, the file name is being changed after deployment. I haven't selected any lowercase transform option.

Comment: I don't know what you're using to bundle the React app but I'd look at that first. Unzip your build output and check the case in the src tag. If it's modified it from the original source, then some part of your bundling process is the cause. Nothing on AWS is going to reach into your HTML file and magically modify the case in your src statement.